# How to send data from child to parent when a button in Parent is clicked in react?

Tags: reactjs

I know how to send data from child to parent component when a button is clicked, but the button should be in child component.
What I want is, how to send data from child to parent when a button is clicked, but the button is in parent component not in child component.

For instance, I have something like this:

Parent component

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const handleChildData = (childData) => {
    console.log(childData);
  }
  return (
    <> 
    <ChildComponent onDataGet={handleChildData} />
    <div>ParentComponent</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Child component

```
function ChildComponent({onDataGet}) {
  const data = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
  }

  // Based on something, execute this function:
  onDataGet(data)

  return (
    <div>ChildComponent</div>
  )
}
```

**I have tried this approach:**

defined a state, on each click the state increments by one, also passed this state to child, in there anytime the state gets changed, `useEffect` in child component will happen and will execute the `onDataGet` function. Like this:

Parent Component

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [isTrigerred, setIsTrigerred] = useState(1);
  const handleChildData = (childData) => {
    console.log(childData);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent onDataGet={handleChildData} gotChanged={isTrigerred} />
      <div>ParentComponent</div>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setIsTrigerred((prev) => prev + 1)}>
        Click Me
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Child Component

```
function ChildComponent({ onDataGet, gotChanged}) {
  const data = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Don't execute in first render
    if (gotChanged !== 1) {
      onDataGet(data);
    }
  }, [gotChanged]);

  return <div>ChildComponent</div>;
}
```

But I'm looking for a better approach, if there is any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caching function of ref can be used to realize the method of parent calling child components.

```js
import {useRef} from 'react'

function ParentComponent() {
  const actionRef = useRef();
  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent ref={actionRef} />
      <div>ParentComponent</div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => {
          const childData = actionRef.current.getData();
          console.log('childData...', childData);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
import {forwardRef} from 'react'

const ChildComponent = forwardRef(function (props, ref) {
  const data = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
  };

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
     // the return object will pass to parent ref.current, so you can add anything what you want.
      return {
        getData: () => data,
      }
    },
    [data],
  );

  return <div>ChildComponent</div>;
});
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you.

But could you please edit the answer a little bit, so that later people will not have hard time in understanding it?

Edit in two places:
ChildComponent
``forwardRef(function ChildComponent(props, ref) {`` it should be ```const ChildComponent = forwardRef(function (props, ref) {```
and in ParentComponent
``<ChildComponent ref={actionRef} onDataGet={handleChildData} />``  since you removed the ``handleChildData`` function, so now you can remove the ``onDataGet`` prop, it can be ``<ChildComponent ref={actionRef} />``

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped :) , I've edited

Comment: @SkyClong, when I call actionRef.current.getData(), its always undefined. its says not a function.

Answer (score 2):

One approach may be to pass a setter for the wanted function in your child component like this :

Parent Component :

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [getChildData, setGetChildData] = useState(() => null);

  const handleChildData = () => {
    const childData = getChildData();
    // etc...
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent getDataSetter={setGetChildData} />
      <div>ParentComponent</div>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleChildData}>
        Click Me
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Child Component :

```
function ChildComponent({ getDataSetter }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only way to use a state for a function, because the setter function
    // can take a callback to set the new value
    getDataSetter(() => () => data);
  }, [data]);

  return <div>ChildComponent</div>;
}
```

Comment: But the ``getDataSetter`` which runs  ``setGetChildData`` causes infinite re-rendering, the ``getDataSetter`` runs in the first render of ``ChildComponent``.

Comment: Yes you're right, i'd let some mistakes in my code. `data` should be a state of the component, not a constant declared on every render